# How to find all disconnected graphs in a node/edge sql representation?

Tags: sql, graph

Given a nodes and a edges tables, how to find all disconnected graphs using TSQL ?

References :
http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/09/07/graphs-in-the-database-sql-meets-social-networks/
http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/subnetworkcreator

Comment: you need to identify the connected components of a graph based on the edge information only. you probably won't achieve this with pure t-sql query because you need to build a transitive closure on a relation without an a priori bound on path lengths. there might be proprietary extensions, check out the docs on hierarchical queries.